# Expand PHP Stack Trace Arguments

Tags: php, arguments, stack-trace

On a stack trace returned from a PHP application in development, long string arguments to a function are truncated when display on the error page:

```
Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO "tb...', Array)
```

How can I expand the query argument so the full text is visible? The server is running PHP 5.3.3.

Comment: This is the same question, thanks for the link. I did not come across that when I searched before my post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [debug_backtrace](http://www.php.net/debug_backtrace) instead. It will give you the whole trace and doesn't trim arguments as far as I know.

On a second thought: You might get away with it by using

```
try {
   ...
} catch (Exception $e)
   var_dump($e->getTrace());
}
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks, the var_dump did the trick. I do not think debug_backtrace will work unless I am misunderstanding it; I cannot modify the file where the exception originates. Is there some way to get var_dump to not produce ellipses?  I think it is truncating some data I need. ``EDIT:`` The other topic provides an alternative solution that should fix the ellipsis issue.

Answer (score 4):

[Starting with PHP 8.0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.other-changes.php#migration80.other-changes.ini#:%7E:text=zend.exception_string_param_max_len,strace.) it is possible to actually raise the limit at which arguments will be truncated.

You can change the newly introduced php.ini setting `zend.exception_string_param_max_len` and set it to any value between 0 and 1000000, the default being 15.

This only affects stack traces generated using [`getTraceAsString()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/throwable.gettraceasstring.php) or by casting an exception to a string (e.g., by printing it).

More information is available [here](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/throwable-stacktrace-param-max-length) or [in the corresponding RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/throwable_string_param_max_len).