# Extended debugging in Laravel

Tags: php, debugging, stack-trace, laravel

Anyway of having the `Stack Trace:` debugging information more extedend... and by that I mainly mean, no having the information trimmed because I might never know when I might need it.

By trimmed text, I mean information like the following:

```
pre>rtrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given</pre>
<h3>Location:</h3>
<pre>/home/tmcwntc/public_html/staging/laravel/bundle.php on line 190</pre>
  <h3>Stack Trace:</h3>
  <pre>#0 /home/tmcwntc/public_html/staging/laravel/laravel.php(42): Laravel\Error::native(2, 'rtrim() expects...', '/home/tmcwntc/p...', 190)
#1 [internal function]: Laravel\{closure}(2, 'rtrim() expects...', '/home/tmcwntc/p...', 190, Array)
#2 /home/tmcwntc/public_html/staging/laravel/bundle.php(190): rtrim(Array, '/')
#3 /home/tmcwntc/public_html/staging/laravel/routing/router.php(458): Laravel\Bundle::handles(Array)
#4 /home/tmcwntc/public_html/staging/laravel/routing/route.php(415): Laravel\Routing\Router::route('ADMIN.IMAGES@UP...', Array)
#5 /home/tmcwntc/public_html/staging/application/controllers/admin/news.php(70): Laravel\Routing\Route::forward('admin.images@up...', Array)
```

Comment: Are you expecting non-trimmed trace messages?

Comment: @AkhyarAmarullah no, but I would like to get them non-trimmed

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace come from the file *laravel/error.php* :

```
echo "
      <h3>Stack Trace:</h3>
      <pre>".$exception->getTraceAsString()."</pre></html>";
```

There is an alternative function at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6076667/194508).