# PHP Exceptions - getTrace replaces scope resolution operator (::) with object operator (->)

Tags: php

I'm designing a simple exception handler to use in my PHP projects. One of the things that always bugged me is the poor stack trace which truncates arguments etc. So I decided to use the `getTrace()`-method to parse the array in a more usable string.
Doing so works fine, but I noticed that static method calls are not represented correctly:

**`getTrace()`:**

```
#3 /system/session.php(38): Session->__construct()
#2 /system/session.php(126): Session->instance()
```

**`getTraceAsString()`:**

```
#1 /system/session.php(38): Session->__construct()
#2 /system/session.php(126): Session::instance()
```

...where `Session` might look like so:

```
class Session(){
  public static function instance(){}
  public function __construct(){}
}
```

Seems like the scope resolution operator (`::`) is replaced by the object operator (`->`) no matter what by `getTrace()`.

Why is that so? Can I do something about it, is there a parameter I'm lacking?

Comment: This doesn't happen on my system, PHP 5.6.12. ` 'type' => string '::' (length=2)`

Comment: PS: no braces after the class name ;)

Comment: Hmm.. It does on my managed hosting server which uses 5.6.12 too...
PS: the real thing is nicely PSR-1-ed ;)

Comment: What's the full output of your call to `Exception::getTrace()`? For me it's an indexed array of assoc arrays. From the example given above it looks like a plain string.

Comment: Thank you, @m02ph3u5. Brought me on the right track :)

Comment: You're welcome. Kein Ding :)

Answer (score 0):

Found it! When using [Stack Overflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31566911/2532203) you should read carefully sometimes.

The original answer uses `sprintf()` to replace the class with the following:

```
...
isset($frame['class']) ? $frame['class'] . '->' : '',
...
```

where it should be:

```
...
isset($frame['class']) ? $frame['class'] . $frame['type'] : '',
...
```

Comment: Guess you should also add this as comment or edit to the original answer.